# How can I display the notification data when app is not running in the foreground

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the new version of firebase_messaging (8.0.0-dev.8). I successfully managed to display to the user the notifications details, when the app is running on the foreground, thanks to the package overlay_support, in this way:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  showOverlayNotification((context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(message.notification.title),
          subtitle: Text(message.notification.body),
          trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                OverlaySupportEntry.of(context).dismiss();
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10000));
});
```

But I can not find a way to achieve the same result when the app is not running, because the function is outside the main Widget class and therefore it has no access obviously to the context. I tried with the get package but without success. As far as now I have just the base code:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data['title']}");

}
```

I would really appreciate any idea